# Why do tests disappear from Microsoft Visual Studio when adding code to existing tests that already work?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automation, visual-studio-2017, nunit

I have hit an issue which I cannot seem to figure out.
My project is on Microsoft Visual Studio (2017), using C#/Selenium/NUnit.

I have tests in my project that are currently working. I went back to these tests to add code so they can run on multiple browsers (mainly Chrome and Firefox).

Work started on this about a month ago, and I was able to add the code to existing tests and those tests run on multiple browsers.
However, when I went back to the remainder of the tests to add this code, I noticed that the test disappeared from the test explorer after cleaning/rebuilding the project.

What could be causing this? I did not make any major changes to the project.
The code in question is below. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

With the code below, the test disappears. If I remove this code, the test is back after a rebuild/build.

**Here is the code I am adding:**

```
namespace NewProject
{
    //adding this for NUnit
    [TestFixture(typeof(FirefoxDriver))]
    [TestFixture(typeof(ChromeDriver))]

    //adding code after the class
    class ProjectAMultipleBrowsers<TWebDriver> where TWebDriver : IWebDriver, new()
{   

    //adding the private declaration below
    private IWebDriver driver;

    TPTMethods tptDo = new TPTMethods();
    URLComparison urlComp = new URLComparison();
    TakeAScreenShot tas = new TakeAScreenShot();
    TakeAScreenShotFullName tasf = new TakeAScreenShotFullName();

    [Test, Order(1)]
    public void ProjectALoginMult()
    {
        //adding the driver object below
        driver = new TWebDriver();
        try
        {
        .....
```

Comment: Update your MsTest nuget packages to the latest.

Comment: I'm using NUNIT. I removed the existing and added the latest one (which I think it already was). Thank you for the quick reply. I'll try this again soon and report back.

Comment: Same thing, nothing changes. Why do the tests disappear? Weird.

Comment: This sometimes happens to me too. I blame it on standard visual studio test explorer, but I have no idea how to fix it. I restart visual studio a couple of times, rebuild and it works again...

Comment: This fixed it in VS2017 with MsTest, but I've been plagued lately with test discovery issues. Like @FCin, it stops working, I restart, it works again for a while.

Comment: It really depends on which minor release of Visual Studio 2017 you are using. Microsoft is working on a few huge changes in that area, so unless you are using 15.5 (ideally 15.6 Preview), what you observed can be something they already fixed.

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you for the help. I am currently using Version 15.4.4.
I dread having to call IT to get this  installed but hopefully a little bit of trouble will stop me from going completely crazy.
Thank you again!

Comment: IT still has to reply to me about this. Apparently they "don't support that version yet". However what still puzzles me is why do the OLD tests still work but when I try to add the same code to run on multiple browsers to newer tests, that the test disappears after I do a clean and rebuild. It's just strange to me. I have never run across this.

Comment: I updated Visual Studio to latest version (15.6.1) and the problem still persists. This is driving me crazy. Thanks for the help and suggestions so far. Keep on pluggin' away...

Comment: Problem solved. I reinstalled Visual Studio then upon seeing the tests missing killed it and restarted it again and reloaded and rebuilt the project numerous times. The tests finally were appearing again. This was definitely weird.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I discovered the test filter icons across the top of the VS Test Explorer.  I inadvertently unknowingly clicked the "not run tests" icon; why did all my tests disappear????!!! I was about to embarrass myself going to my supervisor when I inadvertently clicked the "passed tests" icon; they came back!  But then new tests didn't show.  Lightbulb lit up - I realized it's because I had it filtered for passed tests, not tests that didn't run yet.  There's a "total tests" icon.  Now I know.